# Raster scanning in Matlab

Tags: matlab, raster

I'm attempting to write code for a much larger project that involves fingerprint recognition. I'm trying to use blockproc that takes 3x3 "windows" of my 128x128 matrix. I have a 52x9 matrix where each row of the matrix describes a bifurcation pattern. What I need to do is take 3x3 pieces out of the 128x128 matrix while moving left to right and top to bottom. Each piece is then compared to the bifurcation pattern matrix using a neural network. I need to do rastering to ensure that I'm getting all possible 3x3 representations of the 128x128 matrix. In other words, I need to move to the right 1 pixel, get the 3x3 window, run the network, then move over again 1 pixel, etc...If I can't move to the right anymore (can't create a 3x3 window anymore), I then move down 1 pixel and repeat the horizontal scanning process again. For example:

a simple 3x5 array:

```
A = [10 11 12 13 14;
     15 16 17 18 19;
     20 21 22 23 24];
```

Performing a raster scan with a 2x3 window would result in the following matrices

```
A1 = [10 11 12;
      15 16 17];

A2 = [11 12 13;
      16 17 18];

A3 = [12 13 14;
      17 18 19];

A4 = [15 16 17;
      20 21 22];

A5 = [16 17 18;
      21 22 23];

A6 = [17 18 19;
      22 23 24];
```

Comment: What's the problem?  Are you having difficulty generating A1-A6 algorithmically (or their equivalents, for your data set)?

Comment: I'm having trouble generating A1-A6 from the given matrix. I could probably come up with some for/loop with some if condition to check if anymore 3x3 matrix can be formed, but I would rather try and use one function if possible. I'm not sure which would be computationally faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`colfilt()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/colfilt.html) keeping in mind that MATLAB always operates along rows by default, thus you need to flip A and your block size. You can check the sequence of blocks with [`im2col()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/im2col.html) which is called internally by `colfilt()`:

```
im2col(A', [3,2],'sliding')
ans =
    10    11    12    15    16    17
    11    12    13    16    17    18
    12    13    14    17    18    19
    15    16    17    20    21    22
    16    17    18    21    22    23
    17    18    19    22    23    24
```

where each column is progressively A1, A2, ... or more precisely `reshape(A1',[],1)`, `reshape(A2',[],1)`.

Comment: Thanks for this, never new about this function.

Answer (score 0):

what is wrong with two loops one for the rows, and one for the columns:

```
for row=1:128-3

for col=1:128-3

subMatrix = M(row,col:col+3)

% send to neural network function
end

end
```

Comment: I suppose I could use the loops also since I will need to keep track of the results.

Comment: loops in Matlab are deadly slow

Comment: @user2151446 you are wrong my friend! http://www.matlabtips.com/matlab-is-no-longer-slow-at-for-loops/

Comment: when you need loop and there is no alternative use one